# Query to join two subsets of table data (get it faster)

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

TABLE1:

```
+-----+----------------------+------+-------+
| id  |        value         |weight|  stat |
+-----+----------------------+------+-------+
|  5  | OB_4772FB7E65        |    5 |     1 |
|  6  | OB_A339546708        |    6 |     1 |
|  7  | OB_6CA632C6BC        |    7 |     1 |
|  8  | OB_58757E6E9C        |    8 |     1 |
|  9  | OB_8FF337BE76        |    9 |     1 |
|  10 | OB_CCA8FEC422        |   10 |     1 |
+-----+----------------------+------+-------+
```

TABLE2 (it's a translation table, where there is always an entry with `lang_id`=5 and there may or may not be a translation in other languages (here I show only one another `lang_id`=10). The key `keycode` here is the same as `value` in TABLE1) :

```
+---------------+-----------------+--------+
| id  | lang_id  |    keycode     | teksts |
+---------------+-----------------+--------+
| 940 |  5       | OB_4772FB7E65  | suga1  |
| 941 |  10      | OB_4772FB7E65  | spec1  |
| 946 |  5       | OB_A339546708  | suga2  |
| 947 |  10      | OB_A339546708  | spec2  |
| 949 |  5       | OB_6CA632C6BC  | suga3  |
| 955 |  5       | OB_CCA8FEC422  | suga4  |
| 956 |  10      | OB_CCA8FEC422  | spec4  |
+---------------+-----------------+--------+
```

The needed result (get all keycodes with `stat`=1 and their translation or an empty string if there is no translation. The results must be sorted first by weight and then by basis language):

```
+----+----------------+-----------+
| id |   keycode      | teksts_ln |
+----+----------------+-----------+
|  5 | OB_4772FB7E65  | spec1     |
|  6 | OB_A339546708  | spec2     |
|  7 | OB_6CA632C6BC  |           |
| 10 | OB_CCA8FEC422  | spec4     |
+----+----------------+-----------+
```

I have managed to write a mysql query, it works ok but it is slow. Maybe I have overdone and it can be simplified?

```
SELECT glv.id, glv.keycode, gln.teksts_ln FROM
(SELECT t1.id, t1.weight, t1.value AS keycode, t2.teksts AS teksts_lv FROM TABLE1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 ON t1.value = t2.keycode AND t2.lang_id=5 WHERE t1.stat="1") AS glv
INNER JOIN
(SELECT t1.value AS keycode, t2.teksts AS teksts_ln FROM TABLE1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 ON t1.value = t2.keycode AND t2.lang_id=10 WHERE t1.stat="1") AS gln
ON glv.keycode = gln.keycode ORDER BY glv.weight ASC, glv.teksts_lv ASC;
```

My main concern is how to make the query work faster.

Comment: Is this the exact query? The columns from table t2 (with `t2.lang_id=5`) seem to be not used anywhere. Oh, it's used only for the order by.

Comment: Is there a UNIQUE constraint on `table1 (value)`?

Comment: It is unique in table1, but when I look at the structure I see only `id`=primary key and no other constraints. I'm not allowed to change anything in the structure.

Comment: Is the t2 column named `keycode` or `atslega`? The sample and the code differ.

Comment: sorry, it's `keycode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that can improve your query:

- There is no need for the derived tables (subqueries). You can have a 4-table join in the `FROM` clause.
- Once we do the above, it's obvious that you join `table1` to itself on a column that seems to be `UNIQUE`: (`ON glv.keycode = gln.keycode`). We can remove this join, so the result is a 3-table join.

The query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.value  AS keycode, 
    ln.teksts AS teksts_ln  
FROM
    table1 AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS lv 
      ON t1.value = lv.keycode AND lv.lang_id = 5        
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS ln
      ON t1.value = ln.keycode AND ln.lang_id = 10
WHERE 
    t1.stat = '1' 
ORDER BY 
    t1.weight ASC, lv.teksts ASC ;
```

After we have it working correctly (producing the same results), you can improve efficiency by adding indexes:

- on `table2 (lang_id, keycode, teksts)`
- on `table1 (stat)`

Comment: Thank you! It seemed very promising, however, I got "MySQL returned an empty result set".

Comment: What's the type of column `stat`?

Comment: `stat` is enum('0', '1')

Comment: it works! -  but it's better enclose these values 5, 10, and 1 **in quotes**

Comment: "adding indexes" also sounds like something I'm not allowed. If something happens to this huge database, I can't imagine what happens to me.

Comment: That's why I asked about the type. Enum and string literals need quotes. If `lang_id` is a string type, use quotes for 5 and 10. If it's a numeric type (int, smallint, decimal), don't quote it.

Comment: If you can't add indexes, don't expect good performance. The more the tables grow, the less efficient the various queries will be.

Comment: There are lot of reasons to avoid `enum` type as possible: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `table1.value` also should be indexed as far as used by `JOIN..ON`

Comment: @Kondybas true. A composite index on `(stat, value, weight)` will likely be even better. I didn't want to go into many details, as the choice of indexes would also be affected by the SELECT lists of the actual queries. It seemed that the query posted was only an example.